# How to list all the files in a custom Directory

Tags: android, file, directory, dir

I'm trying to list all the files in a directory I have made, when I create the directory I warp a file for each contact into the dir. I then want to be able to list all those files inside/within the directory. I have tried everything including

```
String a = listFiles().tostring();
```

Yet, nothing happens. To sum it up, I want to list all the files within a custom dir in the SD card.

**Here's my updated code**

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
FileInputStream iStream =  new FileInputStream(path);
String read = path.getbytes().tostring();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to see this tutorial [how to build an android file browser](http://www.anddev.org/building_an_android_filebrowser_list-based_-t67.html) it will help you a lot!!

This [one](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/190013-creating-simple-file-chooser/) list all folder and files in sdcard you can adapt it to what you need by changing the value of **currentDir** in the code

Comment: I don't want a file browser and that's totally useless as I want to see the files inside.

Comment: it's the same idea of yours show list of files in a directory is equivalent to show the tree of files and directory from a root directory. did you checked the link 2 it list folder and files in the sdcard it uses an attribute current directory that is set to 
/sdcard/ by calling 
currentDir = new File("/sdcard/) you can change it to currentDir = new File("/sdcard/your folder) and you get all subdirectory and files in your desired folder

Comment: you don't understand the code  in second link or what im saying!!

Comment: None of it, what functions do I need to use?

Comment: currentDir = new File("/sdcard/TheBlueCat");

Comment: fill(currentDir); and you get all your list in a list view try to follow step by step the tutorial and you will get your  desired result

Answer (score 0):

**This code is travel entire sdcard and list files. that's may be helpful to you ..!**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class DirUtils {

  public static List recurseDir(String dir) {
      String result, _result[];

      result = recurseInDirFrom(dir);
      _result = result.split("\\|");
      return Arrays.asList(_result);
  }

  private static String recurseInDirFrom(String dirItem) {
    File file;
    String  result,list[];

    result = dirItem;

    file = new File(dirItem);
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
      list = file.list();
      File[] fileslist = file.listFiles(new MyDocFileFilter());
    if (fileslist != null) {
      for (File file1: fileslist) {
        System.out.println(file1.getAbsolutePath());
      }
    } 
    else {
      System.out.println("No Subdirectory Found.");
    }
      for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        result = result + "\n" + recurseInDirFrom(dirItem + File.separatorChar + list[i]);
      }
    return result;
  }

 static class MyDocFileFilter implements FileFilter
{
  private final String[] myDocumentExtensions 
               = new String[] {".java", ".png", ".html", "class"};

  public boolean accept(File file) {

    if (!file.isFile())
        return false;

    for (String extension : myDocumentExtensions) {
      if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(extension))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

  public static void main(String arg[]) {
    DirUtils.recurseDir("your path ");



  }
}
```